# HTML templates inside script tags not colorized by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a few angular templates defined inside script tags like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <div class="complex-class listing">
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I like to edit my code from the source tab of Chrome Developer Tools. However, code inside script tags is not colorized. Here's a picture:

[image]

Is there any way to make the html inside the script tag colorized like the rest of the html?

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this problem by removing the type="text/ng-template" attribute.  This has restored highlighting to my mustache templates and they're still being rendered. Not sure if your angular templates will continue to render.  Hope this helps.